# using curl and grep to check status of whether or not an item is in stock?

Tags: html, curl, terminal

Currently I am trying to create a script that will run on linux ubuntu server that will check every 6 hours whether a item is in stock by seeing whether or not the "add to cart" submit button is enabled or not. However, I can't seem to figure out how to use grep to search for that button's status and return some form boolean on whether or not it is enabled/disabled. If I could do this then I could trigger mail to send an email alert to my email.

Here is the button code in the HTML from the website (when in stock):

```
<button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn product-single__cart-submit btn--secondary" disabled="">
    <span id="AddToCartText">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Sold Out
            </font>
        </font>
    </span>
</button>
```

Here is the button code in the HTML from the website (when out of stock):

```
<button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn product-single__cart-submit btn--secondary">
    <span id="AddToCartText">
        <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
            <font style="vertical-align: inherit;">
                Add to Cart
            </font>
        </font>
    </span>
</button>
```

And here is the command I was using:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$( curl -s <url> | grep <AddToCartStatus> )
if [ ! -n "$x" ]
then
    echo Not Available
    exit 1
fi
echo "In Stock" | mail -s "Product is availbe" you@example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact field/string you can simply do something like:

```
curl -Lqs <url> | grep "yourUniqueString" && mail -s "Subject" you@example.com
```

The grep utility exits with one of the following values:

```
0     One or more lines were selected.
1     No lines were selected.
>1    An error occurred.
```

Therefore, the right side of `&&` will only be evaluated if the exit status of the left side is zero.

In case you need more detail while [scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) and if you could use python, I would suggest [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4).

Comment: Thanks! ill give that a try later today